# I am getting "experimental_useOptimistic only works in Client Components" error while using "use client" directive

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a likes component in my Next.js 14 application with the help of the useOptimistic hook.

Here are the imports:

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { experimental_useOptimistic as useOptimistic } from "react";
```

And here's the component:

```
const LikesBar: React.FC<LikesBarProps> = ({ currentUser, postData }) => {
  const [optimisticVotes, setOptimisticVotes] = useOptimistic(
    postData?.votes
  );

  const userVoteExists = postData?.votes?.find(
    (vote) => vote?.userId === currentUser?.id
  );

  const voteHandler = async () => {
    const userOptimisticVoteExists = optimisticVotes?.find(
      (vote) => vote?.userId === currentUser?.id
    );

    setOptimisticVotes((prev) => {
      if (userOptimisticVoteExists) {
        return prev?.filter((vote) => vote?.userId !== currentUser?.id);
      } else {
        // Add a new vote
        return [
          ...(prev as PostVote[]),
          {
            id: Math.random(),
            postId: Math.random(),
            userId: Math.random(),
          },
        ];
      }
    });

    try {
      const vote = await useUpdatePostVotes(
        postData?.id as number,
        postData?.slug as string
      );

      if (vote?.error) {
        toast.error(vote?.error as string);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error as string);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-w-[40px] max-w-[30px] min-h-full bg-green-100 flex justify-center rounded-l-md">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-1 py-6">
        <div
          className="p-[1px] cursor-pointer hover:bg-green-200"
          onClick={voteHandler}
        >
          {userVoteExists && <AiFillLike size={20} color="#4C724D" />}
          {!userVoteExists && <AiOutlineLike size={20} color="#4C724D" />}
        </div>
        <div className="text-sm font-semibold text-green-900">
          {optimisticVotes?.length}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LikesBar;
```

But it doesn't work. I am using the "use client" directive on top of the file.

In the console, I am getting this error:

```
experimental_useOptimistic only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.
```

And in the browser I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.experimental_useOptimistic) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

Seems like a bug.

Here are the Next and React version in my package.json:

```
"next": "^14.0.4",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```